# Icon Tabs as main navigation in app bar

Tags: android, android-layout

How would I go about implementing swipeable icon tabs as the main navigation in an app? Heres a screenie of the popular [Flipboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=flipboard.app&hl=en) app, which demonstrates what im looking for: http://prntscr.com/83607c

I have been looking for an answer to this question for almost a week now, and have asked on several communites yet no one seems to be able to answer how to go about doing something like this. I'm assuming its a ViewPager for the swipeable part, but the only thing I can think of for the tabs would be a `TabLayout`, but this implements tabs "below" the toolbar, eg: http://prntscr.com/83674c which is not what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google recently released Support Design library. Witch contains all the necessary views. You can read more [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)

The views you are interested: 
[TabLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html?utm_campaign=io15&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog) and 
[TabLayouts.Tab](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.Tab.html)

Comment: Yes im aware of the support library as suggested in my post, but any idea how to use `TabLayout` to achieve tabs similar to what I posted? All examples using `TabLayout` that i've seen have implemented the tabs in the space underneath the toolbar/actionbar.

Comment: First thing that comes to my mind is not to use action bar :)

Comment: Implemented `TabLayout` with a .NoActionBar theme and omitted a `Toolbar` from the layout, then set the `TabLayout` to `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`. This seems to have give me the desired effect..just needs some tweaking for a better look. Guess I didnt realize you could implement a `TabLayout` and just completely omit a Toolbar/ActionBar. Thanks! EDIT: for a new challenge..any idea how to get tabs INSIDE a toolbar like [this?](http://40.media.tumblr.com/0f136bf03b655706c8bce495c4cf9cf3/tumblr_ns07c7vFhb1r2wjwko1_1280.png) Without using the deprecated ActionBar.Tab of course.